# Why don't American Mutual funds offer SWP's?

Tags: united-states, india, mutual-funds, regulation

Indian Mutual funds have a feature called SWP [Systematic withdrawal plan]. It's a feature that enables an investor to automatically withdraw the appreciated amount or a specific amount periodically[ monthly, quarterly etc].

[image]

However, I couldn't locate any similar feature here in the US with providers like Merill or M1 finance. What are the regulatory differences between India and the US that none of the Mutual funds in the US offer SWP's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several American fund houses (perhaps even all fund houses) *do* offer systematic (often called *Automated*) Withdrawal Plans (as well as systematic or Automated Investment Plans) for their mutual funds. What might be different from what seems to be the norm in India is *what* the plans offer. Typically, the withdrawal plans allow for

- Redeeming a fixed number of shares each month or each quarter etc on the date that can be chosen by the shareholder and sending the proceeds to the shareholder's bank account

or

- Redeeming as many shares as necessary to send a fixed amount of money to the shareholder's bank account each month or each quarter etc on the date that can be chosen by the shareholder.

Either way, there is a delay of two or three days between the date of the redemption of shares and arrival of the money into the shareholder's account.

Note that, unlike what seems to be the practice in India, the option of withdrawing "the appreciation amount" is *not* available as a general rule; American (stock) mutual funds don't *have* "appreciation amounts" on a monthly basis. There are *bond* mutual funds that pay *dividends* monthly (the interest collected each month from the bond holdings is passed on to the shareholders as *dividends*) and if it is so desired, the shareholder can request that these dividends be sent to the shareholder's bank account instead of being *re-invested* in the fund (re-investment is the default option if one does not make a choice of what to do with dividends and capital gains payouts).
While this effectively works as a systematic withdrawal plan (most bond funds pay dividends on the last day of each month), the amount of cash that is received is by no means exactly the same each month.

Finally, for "other" mutual funds held through *brokerage houses* (e.g. a Vanguard fund held through a Merrill Lynch Brokerage account), systematic withdrawal plans *might* be offered by the brokerages themselves, or most likely they will not. This is because of the way that brokerages hold shares, not as individual shares held by each investor but as a small part of the brokerage's holdings on behalf of all its clients. That is, the earlier descriptions apply to what happens with mutual funds held directly on the mutual fund's website (or through the fund house's *own* brokerage) as opposed to mutual funds held through *another* brokerage account.